# Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать метод size

Tags: c++, очередь

Я написал код для реализации очереди, но по заданию нужно еще написать метод `size`, который вычисляет размер очереди, но я никак не могу придумать как бы это сделать, помогите, пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Node {
    int value;
    Node* next;
};

struct Queue {
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

    Queue() : head(NULL), tail(NULL) { ; }

    Queue& Push(Queue& queue, int value) {
        Node* node = new Node;
        node->value = value;
        node->next = NULL;

        if (queue.head && queue.tail) {
            queue.tail->next = node;
            queue.tail = node;
        }
        else {
            queue.head = queue.tail = node;
        }
        return queue;
    }

    int Pop(Queue& queue) {
        int value = 0;

        if (queue.head) {
            value = queue.head->value;
            queue.head = queue.head->next;
        }

        return value;
    }

    void Print() const {

        Node* temp = head;
        while (temp)
        {
            std::cout << temp->value << " ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    void Size(Queue queue) {
        if (head == tail && head == NULL) {
            std::cout << "Queue is empty";
        }
        else {
            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = (int)queue.head; i < (int)queue.tail; i++) {
                counter++;
            }
            std::cout << counter << std::endl;
        }

    }
};

int main()
{
    Queue queue;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        queue.Push(queue, i + 1);
    }

    for (int i = 5; i > 0; --i)
    {
        queue.Pop(queue);
    }

    queue.Print();
    queue.Size(queue);


}
```

Comment: добавьте ещё служебную переменную `size_t size = 0 ;` в структуру и всё. Аргумент очереди в `Pop` и `Push` не нужен. `int Pop(void){`

Comment: @AlexGlebe и что эта служебная переменная должна делать? Я только начинаю плюсы осваивать просто

Comment: возвращать текущее количество узлов в очереди `size_t Size(){return size;}`. Правда надо не забывать исправлять это количество в функциях `Push` и `Pop`.

Comment: А в `push` и `pop`, когда что-то из них выполняется будем убавлять, либо добавлять к `size`?

Comment: с тонкостями. в `Pop` если очередь **не** пустая, то удалить элемент **и** уменьшить количество `-- size ;`

Comment: Хорошо, попробую реализовать, спасибо и за замечание, что аргументы не нужны спасибо